# Disable the direct setter in Sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I want to have some fields in my Sequelize model that are not settable, but their values are computed.

I use `setDataValue(key, value)` in other setters to set the values for these fields.

However, their values are set *after* I do `setDataValue`.

My current fix is to use a setter which sets back the value:

```
// I know the value was set before and I just want to make sure it remains the same
foo: { ..., set (d, k) { this.setDataValue(k, this.getDataValue(k)) }
```

Is there a better alternative to this? Maybe some kind of option?

I do want to store the values in the database. Using a `VIRTUAL` type doesn't help too much.

Comment: Can you not use hooks. beforeCreate or beforeupdate and reset the fields back

Comment: Using hooks, you won't have to call the setter again yourself

Comment: @Shivam For some reason, the hooks didn't work at all for me (in another context). I find using a hook for this a more complicated solution than my current one, tho... I'm wondering if there is an option like `freeze` or whatever to not allow doing `obj.foo = 42` but allowing `setDataValue("foo", 42)`.